# About Dedicated Video Memory

Tags: memory, video

I have a laptop with the following specs:

- 500 GB Samsung 860 EVO SSD and 1 TB Toshiba HDD (on the DVD caddy)
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
- Intel i5-7200u 2.50Ghz
- 20 GB DDR4 Ram (4 GB soldered and 16 GB added to the slot it has)

My question is about adding a bit more VRAM. Now I have Total Available Graphics Memory 10305 MB and Dedicated Video Memory 128 MB. Is it going to help if I change Dedicated Video Memory from BIOS to the maximum value? Moreover if it helps, is it safe?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is "help what"?

Comment: If it helps for gaming, but eventually...no!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel HD Graphics 620 is an integrated Graphics Card, and its memory usage is dynamic.
Meaning that the Video Memory changes dynamically as per the requirement.
It uses the system’s RAM and could go up to 32 GB, but only up to half of the total RAM
can be dynamically allocated to the GPU.

I wouldn't advice increasing the minimum video memory in the BIOS,
as this would anyway happen automatically when needed.

If the reason for your question is gaming, keep in mind that system RAM is
several times slower than dedicated graphics memory, so the UHD 620 is
totally unsuitable for action gaming. It can do movies and some simple games,
but that's the maximum.

Comment: A little bit disappointed with the answer hahahah! But I agree, Intel hd graphics is not the best choice...

Answer (score 3):

The "dedicated" video RAM on an integrated graphics system such as the Intel 620 you have is the amount of memory permanently taken from your system for the integrated graphics.

Under normal operation the drivers will allocate "shared" RAM in order to work. The fact that both dedicated and shared RAM is you system RAM means that there will be no difference at all between them beyond what they are named and whether they were allocated by the computer firmware or graphics drivers.

The dedicated RAM is likely only useful on a system without proper drivers.

It is where the graphics chip will work on the main screen buffer away from the rest of the system. You will need a minimum amount of memory for the chip to work but the only time increasing it is going to be useful is when you have one or more high resolution screens connected.

With proper drivers the benefit of increasing it will quickly vanish, especially if you don't have a lot of RAM available to begin with and loosing another 256MB could mean that has less memory to do other things.

Comment: Its important to understand that this is a completely different concept from the dedicated VRAM on a discrete GPU. In that case the VRAM is a physically different set of chips (soldered onto the graphics board), with how it is connected being optimized for use by the GPU.